# Add and Display percentage of an amount

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript which calculates the percentage of amount entered, But I am confused how to add amount+percentage and then display.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shares').keyup(function(){
        $('#result').text($('#shares').val() *(10/100));
    });    
});
```

and Here is HTML Code for this

```
        <label>Amount:</label><input name="shares" id="shares" type="text" />
        Total Value: <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#shares').on('keyup', function(){
     var value = parseInt( $(this).val())
     $('#result').html( value + value *.1 ) 
  });
```

Here is working a example : http://jsfiddle.net/3QELR/

You can use `parseFloat` in you need decimal values.

Comment: In Fiddle its working , but Its showing nothing if i am using this on my web page. Can you explain in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#shares').keyup(function(){
var value = parseInt( $(this).val())
    $('#result').text(value + $('#shares').val() *(10/100));
});
```

});